# simplifiy complex expression

Tags: complex-numbers, fractions

How to simplify the following expression:

$$\frac{z-1}{z+1}~, \quad \text{where} z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{-1\}$$

There is just nothing i can come up with, neither in cartesian, nor in polar.

Comment: You mean, write it in $a+bi$ form? What does 'simplify' mean? It looks fairly simple to me.

Comment: Be more clear. What they exactly ask you to do. Simplifying this expression is senseless unless you give more precision.

Comment: I presume you would like to realise the denominator? Write $z  = a+bi$, and try multiplying top and bottom by $\overline{z}$

Comment: I made a mistake in my scratchwork. I've corrected the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression is about as simplified as it can get. That being the case, I assume that when you say "simplify" you mean that you wish to evaluate the expression and need to get rid of the complex denominator. To this end:

Let...

$$f(z)=\frac{z-1}{z+1}$$

Let $v=z-1$, and $w=z+1$. Then...

$$f(z)=\frac{v}{w}=\frac{\bar{w}v}{|w|^2}$$

Substitute $z-1$ and $z+1$ back in for $v$ and $w$, respectively...

$$f(z)=\frac{(\bar{z}+1)(z-1)}{|z+1|^2}$$

The denominator is now a real number, and you may proceed as usual from here.

Comment: How you get $(z-1)^2$

Comment: @HAMIDINESOUMARE Sorry, that's a mistake. I will correct it.

Comment: And you can symplify further. $f(z)=\frac{|z|^2+2i\operatorname{Im}(z)-1}{|z+1|^2}$